# easy_install pip == [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

I have troubles installing pip for python 2.7.3 installed via pythonbrew:

```
pythonbrew update --master
pythonbrew install 2.7.3 --force
```

This fails on the final stage hanging when trying to fetch pip from pip.openplans.org:

```
Installed /Users/andrei/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for distribute==0.6.28
Finished processing dependencies for distribute==0.6.28
After install bootstrap.
Don't have permissions to write /Users/andrei/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info, skipping
Creating /Users/andrei/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info
Creating /Users/andrei/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools.pth
Searching for pip
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Reading http://pip.openplans.org
Download error on http://pip.openplans.org: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known -- Some packages may not be found!
Reading http://pip.openplans.org
Download error on http://pip.openplans.org: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known -- Some packages may not be found!
Reading http://pip.openplans.org
...
```

Running `easy_install pip` also results in the same error. Of course, I can still clone `pip` repo and install it manually, but would be nice to know why it fails via `easy_install`. Any idea?

---

#### Update:

```
$ host pip.openplans.org
pip.openplans.org is an alias for puffin.oddbird.net.
puffin.oddbird.net has address 173.203.85.138
```

Comment: Can't reproduce that here. What does `host pip.openplans.org` give you?

Comment: And running `dscacheutil -flushcache` doesn't improve things?

Comment: Yeah! That worked! Thanks a lot! Please, make it as an answer for other users to know.

Comment: There you go, but your question could also be closed as `Too localized`. It is certainly not a problem specific to python, pip or easy-install.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things might be wrong:

- The DNS lookup is failing for `pip.openplans.org`; test with `host pip.openplans.org`. This could be a local problem; test against the Google DNS servers too with `host pip.openplans.org 8.8.8.8` and `host pip.openplans.org 8.8.4.4`. If all these lookups fail, sacrifice a chicken to the Internet Gods and wait for improvement.
- If the DNS lookup is not failing, but the install is, then your local DNS cache might be holding on to a negative lookup. Flush it with the command `dscacheutil -flushcache`.

Comment: `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` is the proper way to clear the cache if using OSX 10.7 or 10.8.

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem; the command was failing in iTerm2, but not in the default OS X Terminal. Restarting iTerm2 fixed the issue.

Comment: Ughh spent an hour on this issue until I saw this. Thanks for the correct solution.

Comment: I'd love to know what causes iterm to do this.  This happens when trying to use ssh sometimes too.  Very bizarre.

Answer (score 2):

To me, turning WiFi on and off again helped on Max OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Oddly enough, I have lost hours trying to use kafka-python in Mac OS X and I always got "nodename nor servname provided or not known" and I had no idea why. It is running locally and I wasn't expecting a problem with dns or whatever. I tried to turn off wifi as you said, without expecting much, and somehow this worked. I just need to start kafka with no wifi. It is is boring, but I will save some time while I can't find another solution.